# Android Wifi Manager network switching not working

Tags: android, wifimanager, network-connection

In my application I have to show list of access points and then connect to a selected network. When the app is launched and a network is selected the connection goes through and the selected network is also reflected in the phone settings->wifi. But when I try to switch network after launch the following happens

1. the selected network gets connected
2. then its disconnected
3. wifi scans and then connects to the previously connected network

The behavior is same for saved and new network. How do I get the error for the selected network getting disconnected. I am checking for Open and WPA2 network types.

My Code

```
    public WifiConfiguration exists(String SSID)
{
    List<WifiConfiguration> existingConfigs = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration existingConfig : existingConfigs) 
    {

        if (existingConfig.SSID.equals("\""+SSID+"\""))
        {
            return existingConfig;
        }
    }
    return null; 
}

private WifiConfiguration CreateWifiInfo(String SSID, String Password, WifiCipherType Type)
{
    WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();  

    config.SSID = "\"" + SSID + "\"";

    if(Type == WifiCipherType.WIFICIPHER_NOPASS)
    {

        config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    }
    else if(Type == WifiCipherType.WIFICIPHER_WPA2)
    {
        config.preSharedKey = "\""+Password+"\"";
        config.hiddenSSID = true;                    
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
    return config;
}
public boolean Connect(String SSID, String Password, WifiCipherType Type)

    WifiConfiguration tempConfig = this.exists(SSID);

    int netID = -1;
    if(tempConfig == null)
    {
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Network is new, so adding new one.");
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = this.CreateWifiInfo(SSID, Password, Type);
        netID = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "New net ID : " + Integer.toString(netID));
    } else {
        netID = tempConfig.networkId;
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Found net ID: " + Integer.toString(netID));
    }

    boolean bRet = wifiManager.enableNetwork(netID, true);
```

bRet here returns true for the selected network.

Any Suggestions

Thanks
P

Comment: What device are you trying this on?

Comment: HTC one android version 4.3